# RTL8821CE DKMS driver will not work with secure boot enabled

Tags: drivers, secure-boot

After my recent re install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I went into Software and Updates > Additional Drivers and enabled the driver for "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter", following which I rebooted, expecting the driver to work as intended. However, when I try to connect to any network, it kept throwing the error "Activation of network connection failed" (ethernet still works fine, assuming the drivers for that don't need to be separately installed). This issue vanishes if I disable Secure Boot from my UEFI settings. However, I'd like to keep Secure Boot enabled. I have already enrolled the MOK keys into my firmware, so I don't understand what's happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED!
I went to this page on Github (https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) where I'd installed the drivers from previously (before I reset the installation). If you scroll down you can see they mention that you should blacklist rtw88_8821ce. I tried using this before but it didn't make a difference because apparently I was blacklisting the wrong driver. When I ran "sudo lshw -C network" and checked under my Wi-Fi chip, it showed it was using "rtw_8821ce" as its driver. So what I did was I blacklisted rtw_8821ce instead in the file "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf". Following this, I manually deleted all the other drivers I had tried to install and then clean installed rtl8821ce. After the install, just reboot with Secure Boot enabled and now everything works perfectly.